# avoid redundant sass imports in webpack3 client bundle's

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, webpack-3

**I am having a problem, that the common sass styles in my reactjs project end up redundantly in the client bundle…**

1) **I have a set of base styles:**

```
/src/frontend/sass/
    base.scss  the master file, which imports the following…
    ├ common.sass
    ├ colors.sass
    ├ breakpoints.sass
    ├ forms.sass
    └ ...
```

2) **and a webpack project with '.sass' Files per component…**

```
Input/style.sass
Modal/style.sass
TeaserPage/style.sass
…
```

3) **every component style files get's an '@import base.scss' injected in webpack.config, such that I can access variables, mixins or extend a class...**

```
        {
            test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                    { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
                    'postcss-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            data: `@import '${resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'frontend', 'sass').replace(/\\/g, '/')}/base';`,
                            sourceMap: false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })
        },
```

That's all fine for development (with `react-hot-loader`), but in release mode, when I want to build a *compact* client-bundle, this leads to 40x-fold redundancy (…coming from 40 components).

The problem is [→certainly](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/145) [→not](https://github.com/wilsonpage/sass-import-once) [→new](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/1a45d92be8af20bf6b3e8d28c12fdbc853205cce/scss/foundation/_functions.scss), still what would be a proper solution with webpack 3?

- **Concatenation first, processing then?**
- **A (working, non-outdated) `import-once` module?**
- **(terrible workaround): keeping variables/mixins vs. base styles separate** (that would tear forms or breakpoints to pieces)
- **or could I somehow do a webpack config like...?**

  (read ↑bottom up↑, if I understand webpack syntax correctly…)

  ```
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: [
          {
              loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } }, 'postcss-loader',
              3) do your sass→css conversion and post thing
          {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              2) ...load (concatenate to 1) component styles
          },
          {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              1) ...load that base.sass
          },

      ]
  })
  ```

  - …or is there a *non-outdated* (or *these-days-even-included* in webpack itself?) sass-import-once functionality somewhere?

---

I found the [optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin) (for webpack 3 you need `@3.2.0`) which works as some kind of fix. Cleans up the mess as the final stage, but is not, what I would rather want (that is: avoid creating the mess by importing once / concatenation first …).

Comment: use **extend** or **mixin**. Wrap all your *base.scss* classes inside inside a mixin or function or partials. Call where ever you want. You can import it n-number of times but will not cause redundancy or repeated code spitting out.

Comment: mixins can contain (not only properties or maybe sub-classes but) a full set of sass files? – do you have a sample?